# speed up OCR with pytesseract

Tags: ocr, python-tesseract

I'm using pytesseract on large image dataset, unfortunately, It's so slow, Is there any way to use gpu to speed up the process or any other remedy to cure the low speed?

The line of code I use for each image is this :

### `text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))`